# Regex match only phone numbers and not date

Tags: php, regex

My regex:
https://regex101.com/r/wM0oy1/2/

```
/(((?!(([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])\.(19|20)\d\d)))
(\+?[0-9][0-9()-s+\s]{5,20}[0-9]))/
```

I only want it to match phone numbers, but atm i dont get it working, this is what i thought would work but i only get 1 match

Test 22.13.2018            <-- don't want match on date

Test 09234343              <-- want match on phone number

Test 0171 443 343 433      <-- want match on phone number

Test 0943 34445            <-- want match on phone number

Test +49(0)94234 3434 34   <-- want match on phone number

Test 09743/1443            <-- wan't match on phone number

Test 02.12.2017            <-- don't want match on date

Test 2017                  <-- don't want match on date

I basically wanna exclude the dates.

I want this to match phonenumbers only and not dates

```
\+?[0-9][0-9()-s+\s]{5,20}[0-9]
```

and accept this pattern as exception

```
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(0[1-9]|1[012])\.(19|20)\d\d
```

Comment: Dates are dd/mm/yyyy format while d and m can also be 1 digit unlike year

Comment: How do you know that your first example is not a phone number? It could easily be. And it is definitely not a date :-)

Comment: It is used to get rid of phone numbers, i use it so people cant share their phone numbers and have to use the platform

Comment: for start - https://regex101.com/r/59NWJ7/1

Comment: i would need something like is "phonenumber" and not "date" at the same time, that is what i was trying

Comment: Did you check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63308590/3832970)? It should work for you. If not, please let know what still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt function checkdate in php and check if it is a valid date.

Comment: Dates are dd/mm/yyyy format while d and m can also be 1 digit unlike year, atleast that is the way i want it to be

Comment: I want to remove phone numbers with this not check date, but i need to regex for "is phone number and not date" at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Use SKIP-FAIL:

```
(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])\.(?:19|20)\d\d(*SKIP)(*F)|\+?[0-9][0-9()-s+\s]{5,20}[0-9]
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/8cjxZ0/1)

Once `(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])\.(?:19|20)\d\d` is matched, SKIP-FAIL operators omit the match, and the `\+?[0-9][0-9()-s+\s]{5,20}[0-9]` will never match a date substring.